# Javascript - How to toggle an element in contenteditable as execCommand?

Tags: javascript, toggle, element, contenteditable, execcommand

I want to toggle **B** tag if selected:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<p><b>Zeffer !</b></p>
</div>
<button id="bold">Bold</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `click event listener` to the button, which executes the `execCommand`.

```
var bold = document.getElementById('bold');

bold.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
});
```

When selecting the text inside the `contenteditable` div and then clicking the button, it will toggle to either bold or non-bold; depending on its' current status.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfqe4s1r/) for a live demo.